# Django Import Issue

Tags: python, django

Im running Django with Apache in a virtual env.
All is working fine but 1 out of 10 requests result in a HTTP 500 error

When I look at the logs I see,

```
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182] mod_wsgi (pid=32122): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/juniper/config/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     self.load_middleware()
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     __import__(name)
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 135, in load_module
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     mod.__package__))
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]   File "/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 131, in load_module
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182]     cls = getattr(mod, self.name)
[Thu Jul 17 10:52:26 2014] [error] [client 10.9.16.182] AttributeError: Couldn't find configuration 'Local' in module 'boxy':  'module' object has no attribute 'Local'
```

The app that is returning the 500 is juniper. But I see that the error is looking for the Local configuration in boxy (?)

Heres my **wsgi.py**

```
import os,sys,site

site.addsitedir("/opt/pythonenv/juniper/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append('/opt/juniper/')
#sys.path.append('/opt/')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Local')

#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The MIDDLEWARE settings are :

```
class Local(Common):
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = Common.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + ('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',)

class Common(Configuration):
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    )
```

Am i missing something simple ??

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: Please give value for `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: MIDDLEWARE added to question. Ill have to add the file structure later.

Comment: What is that `site-packages/configurations/importer.py` things ? It's definitly not part of Django...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by

- removing wgsi from apache
- installing gunicorn
- and then sending traffic to apache -> gunicord -> django

Thanks,